# Wind speed measuring using Hall sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, hall-effect

[image]

Hi!
I require your help regarding a problem I’m encountering.
I am trying to measure wind speed using Hall sensor, Neodymium magnet & below mentioned code. But I only get “0” value for both RPM & KPH values. Can you help me to solve this?

```cpp
volatile byte revolutions;

unsigned int rpmilli;
float speed;

unsigned long timeold=0 ;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), rpm_fun, RISING);

    revolutions = 0;
    rpmilli = 0;
    timeold = 0;
}

void loop()
{
    if (revolutions >= 1) {
         //Update RPM every 20 counts, increase this for better RPM resolution,
         //decrease for faster update

         // calculate the revolutions per milli(second)
         rpmilli = revolutions/(millis()-timeold);

         timeold = millis();
         revolutions = 0;
         // WHEELCIRC = 2 * PI * radius (in meters)
         // speed = rpmilli * WHEELCIRC * “milliseconds per hour” / “meters per kilometer”

         // simplify the equation to reduce the number of floating point operations
         // speed = rpmilli * WHEELCIRC * 3600000 / 1000
         // speed = rpmilli * WHEELCIRC * 3600

         speed = rpmilli 1.288053600;

         Serial.print(“RPM:”);
         Serial.print(rpmilli * 60000 ,DEC);
         Serial.print(" Speed:");
         Serial.print(speed,DEC);
         Serial.println(" kph");
    }
}

void rpm_fun()
{
    revolutions++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rpmilli = revolutions/(millis()-timeold);
```

All variables in this line are of type `int`, so this is an integer division. When the time delta in ms is larger than the number of revolutions it counted, this always returns 0. You need to change this to:

```
rpmilli = ((float)revolutions)/(millis()-timeold);
```

and change `rpmilli` to float.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help